# Hql Query to Bind a Data Member

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, struts, hql

```
Query qry = session.createQuery("From RegistrationBean where ? = ?");
qry.setString(0,searchCriteria);
qry.setString(1,searchField);
searchList =(ArrayList<RegistrationBean>) qry.list();
```

`RegistrationBean` Entity class has `userName, address, age` fields..
I want to search a user by search criteria such as `userName, address` etc. using the above single query...
But the query is returning me zero results even though the user exist..

what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both parameters are set to 0 position, the second is not set. The position parameter should be set sequentially.

```
qry.setParameter(0,searchCriteria);
qry.setParameter(1,searchField);
```

But the field name should pass in the following way

```
String queryString = "from RegistrationBean as model where model." + propertyName   + "= ?";
Query queryObject = getSession().createQuery(queryString);
queryObject.setParameter(0, value);
return queryObject.list();
```

Comment: sorry...while posting the ques I typed both as 0...Above solution dint work for me...it is still returning me zero results

Comment: @user1831612 Look the example of code. Parameter names are passed when you call `createQuery`.

Comment: How can i have a Like query?
Query qry = session.createQuery("From RegistrationBean as rb where rb."+searchCriteria+"like %?%");
is not working for me

Comment: createQuery("from RegistrationBean as rb where rb."+searchCriteria+" like '%"+searchField+"%'");

Answer (score 0):

Try in the following way:

```
Query qry = session.createQuery("select * from RegistrationBean where :searchCrit = :searchValue");
qry.setString(":searchCrit",searchCriteria);
qry.setString(":searchValue",searchField);
searchList =(ArrayList<RegistrationBean>) qry.list();
```

It is more appropriate to use it like this instead of setting indexes (your problem is that you set both to 0), because if you change something in your query you might need to change your setters afterwards.

Comment: sorry...while posting the ques I typed both as 0...Above solution dint work for me...it is still returning me zero results..

Comment: Did you try the solution I proposed with placeholders of the type ":placeHolder" for the parameters? Are you sure you are not getting any errors? It seems you are lacking a "select *" or select something before the "From Registration" statement.